# php regular expression remove dashes only from digits

Tags: php, preg-replace

i am looking for a reg exp to replace dashes (-) only from words that contain digits

examples

> string : x-y-z 1-2-3-4 should become x-y-z 1234 
>       (x-y-z stays and 1-2-3-4 replace dashes)
>
> string : 1-2-3-4       should become 1234
>
> string : x-y-z         should stay   x-y-z

Any help is appriciated

Comment: @Amadan sorry x-y-x is typo mistake and i have edit it

Comment: Use `preg_replace("/(\d)-/", "$1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\d)-(?=\d)/', '', $string)
```

Find all dashes preceded by a digit and followed by a digit, and nuke them.

Comment: fails for smth like x-y-z-2

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful for you;

```
<?php
$inputStr = 'x-y-z 1-2-3-4 x-y-z';

$outputStrWords = [];
$inputStrWords = explode(' ', $inputStr);
foreach ($inputStrWords as $key => $word) {
    $charactersInWord = explode('-', $word);
    $allCharsDigit = true;
    foreach ($charactersInWord as $char) {
        $allCharsDigit &= is_numeric($char) ? true : false;
    }

    $outputStrWords[$key] = $word;
    if($allCharsDigit) {
        $outputStrWords[$key] = str_replace('-', '', $word);
    }
}

$outputStr = implode(' ', $outputStrWords);

echo $outputStr; exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$x = preg_replace('/(?=(^|\s)\d+)-|-(?=\d+(\s|))/', '', 'x-y-z 1-2-3-4');
```

Answer (score -2):

you can do it like this

```
$string = preg_replace('/-/',' ',$string);
```

also you can do it without using regex

```
$string = str_replace('-','',$string);

$string = strtr($string, '-', '');
```

Comment: This will do more than OP requires (remove e.g. `@`, whereas OP only asks for `-`), and will do things that OP explicitly does not want (remove dashes between letters).

Comment: It still does the same thing. It sill removes `-` where it shouldn't